# Twitter like registration process. Avoiding bots

Tags: php, registration, captcha, email-verification

I want to enable public registration on my website. I don't want to use Captchas, instead I want to send an e-mail verification link to the users that sign up. By the way, I'm using PHP over WAMP.

I'm taking twitter as an example, When you reach https://twitter.com/signup ,you can enter e-mail, password and username. Then you have limited functionality until you confirm your email.

My question is, does twitter have any antibot mechanism or are they open to massive registrations? I don't see any type of captcha or human verification, so yes, you've got limited functionality unless you confirm, but then on the other side, it musn't be very complicated to create a bot to fill up the form and do email autoconfirmation, unless they have some hidden antibot stuff.

I like from Twitter that the sign up process is very easy for the users, but I'm afraid I'm open to massive registrations in my site, if I take them as an example.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework? Or are you building your PHP project from scratch?

Comment: I'm building from scratch with PHP 5.5 and MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is build your registration form like you see at Twitter, and build some kind of custom permissions system like for example StackOverflow has to determine what a user can and can not do. It could be as simple as a boolean value stating confirmed/unconfirmed or as elaborate as StackOverflow with their levels and such.

When a user registers, you send him an email containing a link to a page followed by a random string as a GET parameter. When you land on that page, the PHP script will check the users table in your database and if it is a match, grant extended permissions to that user.

If you want to clean up unconfirmed users automatically, you could also store the datetime of registry and periodically kick out everyone who has not verified their email after X days.